# What the different between a script request and an xhr request?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am unclear to the concept of between sending a request through a script tag or through an iframe and an xhr request. are them all http request? can they replace each other?

Comment: If you're not using web sockets, *everything* is an HTTP request. Implicit HTTP requests initiated from things like `<script>`, `<link>`, and `<img>` tags are GET requests. An XHR can initiate a request with any method, but they're subject to additional security rules.

Answer (score 3):

> are them all http request?

Yes.

> can they replace each other?

No, not usually. One example: You can load a script via a `script` tag from any origin, but by default you can only use Ajax (XHR, `fetch`, etc.) to retrieve information from the same origin because you're restriced by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). (That restriction can be relaxed by the server you're getting the information from via [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/).) (Accessing the actual document information from a cross-origin `iframe` is restricted in the same way.)